# Sum custom field values of particular taxonomy

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I need to sum custom field values of a custom post type with a particular taxonomy ONLY.

For example...

- Custom Post Type: Computers
- Taxonomy: Laptops
- Custom Field: Quantity

How can I get the quantity value of "laptop" "computers" only?
I have been using the following to sum custom fields of ALL taxonomies... can it be modified to restrict to certain taxonomies?

```
$total_quantity = array();
$meta_key = 'inventory-quantity'; //custom field meta key
$total_quantity = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s", $meta_key));
echo 'QTY '.array_sum( $total_quantity );
```

Also just tried this as suggested and get a value of 0 returned..

```
$total_puppies = array();
$meta_key = 'wpcf-litter-puppies';//set this to your custom field meta key
$total_puppies = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare
("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta as pm
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships as tr ON (pm.post_id = tr.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) 
WHERE 1
AND tt.taxonomy = 'litter-type'
AND pm.meta_key = %s", 
$meta_key));
echo 'Total Puppies '.array_sum( $total_puppies );
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to `JOIN` a couple of tables.

```
SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta as pm
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships as tr ON (pm.post_id = tr.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) 
WHERE 1
AND tt.taxonomy = 'laptop'
AND pm.meta_key = 'quantity'
```

I am *fairly sure* that is right. These things are complicated.

If your `meta_value` is a number-- that is, no punctuation or other spaces-- you should be able to use `SUM(meta_value)` and avoid the `array_sum` after the fact.

Comment: That didn't work... or either I did it wrong... here is the code I used - results was 0...<?php
$total_puppies = array();
$meta_key = 'wpcf-litter-puppies';//set this to your custom field meta key

$total_puppies = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare
("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta as pm
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships as tr ON (pm.post_id = tr.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) 
WHERE 1
AND tt.taxonomy = 'litter-type'
AND pm.meta_key = 'puppies'", 
$meta_key));

echo 'Total Puppies '.array_sum( $total_puppies );
?>

Comment: [edit] your question please. Code in the comments is nearly impossible to read.

Comment: You are using `$wpdb->prepare` but there is no replacement marker in your query. `AND pm.meta_key = 'puppies'` should be `AND pm.meta_key = %s`

Comment: Sorry wrong code, this is what I used...

    <?php
    $total_quantity = array();
    $meta_key = 'inventory-quantity'; //custom field meta key
    $total_quantity = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare
    ("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta as pm
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships as tr ON (pm.post_id = tr.object_id) 
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) 
    WHERE 1
    AND tt.taxonomy = 'laptop'
    AND pm.meta_key = 'quantity'", 
    $meta_key));
    echo 'QTY '.array_sum( $total_quantity );
    ?>

Comment: Sorry, updated the original question...

Comment: Isn't the $meta-key after the query the replacement marker? Sorry, new to all of this and trying to find my way around.

Comment: No. That is the replacement string. That is the value that will be used to replace the marker. Look up `sprintf`. `$wpdb->prepare` works like that, but is more limited.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the SQL statements to work so I came up with another approach (not the best way to do this, but it works)...

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'puppies',
    'taxonomy' => 'litter-type',
    'term' => 'previous-litters',
    'posts_per_page' =>-1
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : ?> 
<?php    
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $amt = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-litter-puppies', true); ?> 
    <?php if ($amt) {$previous_puppies_total += $amt;}; ?>
    echo $total; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php echo 'Puppies from previous litters: '.$previous_puppies_total; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```